# Java - cannot be resolved to a type?

Tags: java, types

I have a problem with my code. In my class this section of code always gives me an error saying

> LinkedList cannot be resolved to a type

and I'm not sure what to do. it is only the parts where `((LinkedListInArrayPolynomial)other).count)` is in the code.

```
    public PolynomialInterface add(PolynomialInterface other)
        {
            int location = NUL;
            int previous = NUL;
            int count = 0;
            int count1 = 0;
            int cur1 = this.curPos;
            int count2 = 0;
            int cur2= ((LinkedListInArrayPolynomial)other).curPos;
            {
                if(poly[cur1].getExpo() < poly[cur2].getExpo())
                {
                    location = getNode();
                    poly[location] = new AListNode(poly[cur2].getExpo(), poly[cur2].getValue());
                    if (count != 0)
                    {
                        poly[previous].next = location;
                    }
                    previous = location;
                    cur2 = poly[cur2].next;
                    if(count == 0)
                        ((LinkedListInArrayPolynomial)sum).curPos = location;
                    count2++;
                    count++;
                }
                else if(poly[cur1].getExpo() > poly[cur2].getExpo())
                {
                    location = getNode();
                    poly[location] = new AListNode(poly[cur1].getExpo(), poly[cur1].getValue());
                    if(count != 0)
                    {
                        poly[previous].next = location;
                    }
                    previous = location;
                    cur1 = poly[cur1].next;
                    if(count == 0)
                        ((LinkedListInArrayPolynomial)sum).curPos = location;
                    count2++;
                    count++;
                }

                else 
                {
                    location = getNode();
                    poly[location] = new AListNode(poly[cur1].getExpo(), poly[cur1].getValue() + poly[cur2].getValue());
                    if(count != 0)
                    {
                        previous = location;
                        cur1 = poly[cur1].next;
                        cur2 = poly[cur2].next;
                        if(count == 0)
                            ((LinkedListInArrayPolynomial)sum).curPos = location;
                        count2++;
                        count1++;
                        count++;
                    }
                }
while(count1 < this.count)
            {
                location = getNode();
                    poly[location] = new AListNode(poly[cur1].getExpo(), poly[cur1].getValue());
                if(count != 0)
                {
                    poly[previous].next = location;
                }
                previous = location;
                cur1 = this.poly[cur1].next;
                count1++;
                count++;
            }
            while(count2 < ((LinkedListInArrayPolynomial)other).count)
            {
                location = getNode();
                    poly[location] = new AListNode(poly[cur2].getExpo(), poly[cur2].getValue());
                if(count != 0)
                {
                    poly[previous].next = location;
                }
                previous = location;
                cur2 = poly[cur2].next;
                count2++;
                count++;

            }
            return sum;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post all required code (e.g. LinkedListInArrayPolynomial) please

Comment: Can you also post the whole stack trace..

Comment: I can't see `((LinkedListInArrayPolynomial)other).count)` anywhere in your code...

Comment: Did you miss an import?

Comment: sorry, here is the rest of the method, i guess the problem i'm having is that no matter what method it's in LinkedListInArrayPolynomial always gives the same error : "Cannot be resolved to a type".

Comment: This is the add method, but in the subtract method i get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

An obvious error is: int location = NUL;

Unless you have a constant of type int/Integer with that name.

Comment: i do have a constant of type int called NUL in the beginning of the class and i initialized it to -1.

Answer (score 0):

Have you provided an import statement at the top of the code after package declaration ?

```
import {LinkedListInArrayPolynomial's package}.LinkedListInArrayPolynomial;
```

Comment: it is a total of 8 classes and they're all under one package, the import statement you are talking about, is it import java.util.LinkedList? because I did forget that but when i entered it , it did nothing.